# How to implement ng-if within ng-repeat for array of objects condition?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.masterData=[
{id:1,Name:"name1"},
{id:2,Name:"name2"},
{id:3,Name:"name3"},
{id:4,Name:"name4"},
{id:5,Name:"name5"},
{id:6,Name:"name6"},
{id:7,Name:"name7"},
{id:8,Name:"name8"},
{id:9,Name:"name9"}
]

   
$scope.columnData = {
    key1 : {
        id : 1,
        name : 'name1'
    },
    key2 : {
        id : 2,
        name : 'name2'
    },
    
    key3 : {
        id : 11,
        name : 'name3'
    }
};
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in columnData">
      
    
      <td ng-if="masterData.id.indexOf(value.id)==-1">
    
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" > {{value.name}} </a>
      </td>
      <td ng-if="masterData.id.indexOf(value.id)!=-1">
    
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" ng-disabled="true"> {{value.name}} </a>
      </td>
      
      
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

In the above code i have one array contains multiple objects and i have one dictionary.I write code for checking dictionary object exists in array or not using ng-if but its not working properly. I want to disable the what are the dictionary ids are present in array those are disabled using angularjs in html view only.
This is my plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jEAVSNeGVZgyoBCbKm2b?p=preview

Comment: what should your result ? can u post.

Comment: I want to disable the id 1,2 because these two ids are present in array.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to your scope like this

```
$scope.isInMasterData = function(id) {
  return $scope.masterData.map(function(obj) { return obj.id }).indexOf(id) !== -1;
};
```

In your html you could then call it like so

```
<td ng-if="!isInMasterData(value.id)">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" > {{value.name}} </a>
</td>
<td ng-if="isInMasterData(value.id)">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" ng-disabled="true"> {{value.name}} </a>
</td>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rpTCyHRrPs5wio0to4F6?p=preview)

Comment: See the plunker link - the ng-if is working which I thought was your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty href if the link is disabled

HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in columnData">
  <td>
    <a ng-href="{{!isInMasterData(value.id) ? '' : '#'}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark"> {{value.name}} </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Add the function as written in the other comment:

```
$scope.isInMasterData = function(id) {
return $scope.masterData.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.id == id;
 });
};
```

Another alternative for js function is:

```
$scope.searchInMasterData = function(id) {
return $scope.masterData.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.id == id;
 });
};
```

and in this case the HTML code should be:

```
<a ng-href="{{searchInMasterData(value.id).length == 0 ? '' : '#'}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark"> {{value.name}} </a>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKXNoX?editors=1010#anon-login/%22Codepen%22)